# testing componentDidUpdate enzyme reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test this simple componentDidUpdate and I can not seem to get it covered for the life of me.

this how I'm testing it.

```
  it('should run storeCardDesigns if conditions are met on componentDidUpdate', () => {
    const props = {
      isLoading: () => false,
      loadedWithErrors: () => false,
      storeCardDesigns: jest.fn(),
      availableCardDesigns: [],
    };

    const renderedModule = shallow(<GalleryModal {...props} />);
    renderedModule.setProps({ availableCardDesigns: [{ id: 'test1' }, { id: 'test2' }] });
    expect(renderedModule).toMatchSnapshot();
```

});

[image: z]

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to test against `storeCardDesigns` (this covers both `if/else` cases -- otherwise, to cover just the `else` case, you can simply update a prop and expect storeCardDesigns to not have been called):

```js
it("calls storeCardDesigns if the 'availableCardDesigns' prop changes", () => {
    const storeCardDesigns = jest.fn();
    const availableCardDesigns = [{ id: 'test1' }, { id: 'test2' }];

    const initialProps = {
      isLoading: false, // why is this a function? why not a simple boolean?
      loadedWithErrors: false, // why is this a function? why not a simple boolean?
      storeCardDesigns, // utilizes mock fn above
      availableCardDesigns: [], // initially empty
    };

    // shallow wrap component with initial props
    const wrapper = shallow(<GalleryModal {...initialProps} />);

    // update availableCardDesigns prop to trigger CDU lifecycle
    wrapper.setProps({ availableCardDesigns }); 

    expect(storeCardDesigns).toHaveBeenCalledWith(availableCardDesigns);

    // clear mock
    storeCardDesigns.mockClear();

    // update another prop update to trigger CDU
    wrapper.setProps({ isLoading: true });

    expect(storeCardDesigns).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for adding the comments to explain the thought process. That was really helpful.

The issue now is that this `    expect(storeCardDesigns).toHaveBeenCalledWith(availableCardDesigns);
` is being called 0 times.

Comment: Several debugging steps to try: 1.) Check for spelling errors 2.) console log `availableCardDesigns` within the component's CDU to make sure it's being changed. If it's not being changed and the spelling is correct, then you may need to use `mount` instead of `shallow`.